# Show Youtube like preview on the listImageview in android recyclerview

Tags: android

**Currently what I am doing**:

- I am having a list of items that I show in a recycler view
- Each item has an image and a title (Basically its the list of videos)
- On click of each item, I show video in a detail screen

**What I want to achieve**:

- How to show a preview in Imageview as youtube does on focusing on one
  of an item of listview
- Is there any existing library that handles this

Comment: What do you mean by Preview ? do you mean the Video playback on List in Mute ? or showing the thumbnail ?

Comment: @ADM .... In the Thumbnail like a gif that changes ! ... you can see it happen on youtube thumbnails :)

Comment: I am sure That's not a GIF . Its the Video player itself with interaction disabled and volume mute.

Comment: @ADM .... Okay, So if we show many players in a list view .... `Ex: Exoplayer` in our case ... wouldn't it affect the performance

Comment: No . At one time only one video will be playing . I am sure you will find some samples for it . It's a very common thing these days .